# Show Program only in system tray [kdocker]

Tags: bash, taskbar, system-tray

i want to hide a program (gitkraken) from taskbar and only show it in the system tray.
for this purpose i wrote a little bash script, using kdocker, to achieve this.

```
#!/bin/bash
gitkraken
sleep 10
kdocker -f -t
```

basically it starts gitkraken, waits 10sec, then runs kdocker.

> -f = put active window in system tray
>
> -t = hide it from task

however, the kdocker -f -t commands starts after like 1minute, not 10 seconds, why?

is there any easy alternative on how to do this?

Comment: How long does `gitkraken` take?

Comment: about 5-7 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it in Linux Mint Sarah and Thunderbird 60.2.1. Previously Thunderbird had plugin to put it in the system tray which stopped working one fine day after a Thunderbird update.

Similar solutions are available and I have adapted it according to my need. Possibly you just need to replace Thunderbird with gitkraken.

Finally I put this script in my filesystem and added it to "Startup Applications" which will run this script on startup. So, in effect, Thunderbird starts up, is visible in the system tray, but the window stays for me to login.

```
#!/bin/bash
thunderbird &
while [ true ]
do
   sleep 7
   status=$(wmctrl -l | grep "Thunderbird")
   if [ "$status" != "" ] ; then
      break
   fi
done
kdocker -m thunderbird
```